# Supported versions of nginx

Tags: nginx, version, ubuntu-18.04

Trustwave PCI (Payment Card Industry) compliance has just failed with 'The remote host is running a version of nginx that is no longer supported'. I am running the latest LTS version of ubuntu server 18.04 with the latest version of nginx 1.14.2.

I have looked on line, but I cant find a list of which versions of nginx are still supported/unsupported. I would like to find either a way to determine if 1.14.2 *is* supported, or an authoritative list to dispute the finding.

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/download.html?_ga=2.63802479.1104033220.1558590074-1880788572.1558590074 When it is called legacy, you shouldn't expect it to be supported any more.

Comment: To install a later version of nginx, you have to first uninstall it. https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lex-li, everything listed under "legacy" is unsupported [here](https://nginx.org/en/download.html?_ga=2.63802479.1104033220.1558590074-1880788572.1558590074), though I thought nginx 1.14.2 was the latest because using the ppa for a stable version of nginx, apt install was telling me that it *was* the latest version. Recently nginx must have changed their install so that if you want to upgrade past 1.14, you need to uninstall nginx, then follow the instructions [here](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu)

Comment: Sometimes, the meaning goes beyond that. I have a case study here for Docker, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-cost-of-open-source-solutions-a-case-study-on-red-hat-and-docker-27f8cdad5969 When an open source product comes from different origins (a Linux distribution and its own vendor), it usually indicates different support policies. A vendor might emphasize its own source, so as to draw users towards it (and its commercial upgrades).